# Dropdown menu displayed on left of screen

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, position, dropdown

I've been experimenting with dropdowns a lot. Now my menu looks exacly like how I want it, but my dropdown is displayed on the left of the screen and not directly under its parent.

**Example:**

```css
.nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
ul li a {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}
ul li ul {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
ul li ul li {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Page1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Page 1.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Page 1.2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Page 1.3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Page 1.4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Page2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Page 2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Page 2.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On hover, `ul li ul` should become visible under `ul li`, but `ul li ul` is displayed on the left of my screen. I've tried different positions for all the elements, but I couldn't figure it out.

**Expected result:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
ul li {
  position: relative; 
}
```

The parent element of an `absolute` positioned element has to have a `position` value other than `static` (which is the default, even if it's not included in the CSS)

EDIT: This parent element has to be a block element (your `<li>`currently are inline elements), so you also have to add that:

```
ul li {
      position: relative; 
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

See also the updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrqyJr

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I added an image to my question with an example.

Comment: `display: inline-block` did it for me! `position:relative` is not needed.

Comment: but it's still better if you add it: that way the position reference for your submenu is really its main menu entry, and not the nav element or anything else.